# I'm emiting a value from the watcher but this value is not received in the parent component Vue 3 Select component

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

I have a Custom select component which emits a value in the watch method but when I have to get that value, is not shown in the parent component. (VUE 3)

this is my select component:

```html
<template>
  <div class="input-group">
    <label class="label">{{ label }}</label>
    <select v-model="select">
      <option v-for="option in options" :value="option.id" :key="option.id">
        {{ option.name }}
      </option>
      <option :value="select" disabled hidden>Select...</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
  import { ref, watch, getCurrentInstance } from "vue";
  export default {
    name: "Select",
    props: {
      options: {
        type: Array,
        required: true,
      },
      select: {
        type: String,
      },
      label: {
        type: String,
      },
    },
    setup(props) {
      const { emit } = getCurrentInstance();
      const select = ref(props.value);
      watch(select, (value) => {
        emit("input", value);
      });

      return {
        select,
      };
    },
  };
</script>
```

This is the implementation in the parent component

```html
<template>
<Select
    label="Group Name"
    :options="questions_groups"
    v-model="groupName"
    />
<template>
<script>
......
.....
const groupName = ref(null);
<script/>
```

I need to know why I cannot get the value od the v-model variable in the implementation

Answer (score 2):

for vue3 (because it supports multiple models the event name changed) you need to use `update:modelValue`

```js
watch(select, (value) => {
  emit("update:modelValue", value);
})
```

---

for clarity...

`modelValue` is the default model's name, so
`<input v-model="searchText" />` is equivalent to  `<input v-model:modelValue="searchText" />`

having multiple models allows use such as:

```html
<UserName
  v-model:first-name="first"
  v-model:last-name="last"
/>
```

more info at https://vuejs.org/guide/components/v-model.html#component-v-model